# Custom error page to handle Axis2Fault , EPR not found

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, apache-axis

I have created a new web service project which works fine, when trying to access using correct url i am able to view the wsdl on the browser.

But when a wrong url is typed stack trace is being shown on the browser as below :

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is //services/TestService?wsdlkdfl and the WSA Action = null. If this EPR was previously reachable, please contact the server administrator.
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.DispatchPhase.checkPostConditions(DispatchPhase.java:102)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:329)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:168)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.util.RESTUtil.invokeAxisEngine(RESTUtil.java:144)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.util.RESTUtil.processURLRequest(RESTUtil.java:139)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet$RestRequestProcessor.processURLRequest(AxisServlet.java:837)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doGet(AxisServlet.java:273)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
```

how to handle this scenario to show a blank page rather than showing stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by changes in axis2.xml file as below :

"sendStacktraceDetailsWithFaults" parameter to > false

"DrillDownToRootCauseForFaultReason" parameter to > false

Previously these two parameters were true, due to which whole of the stack trace was getting displayed.

Hope this helps for some one with same issue. I couldn't find much in the internet.